# Selenium random error not making sense

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have around 13 tests in a Specflow feature file, when i run these tests they all pass except for one on an intermittent basis (it sometimes passes without issue)

When it fails I get one of the following messages:

- unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
- chrome not reachable

At first, I thought it might be due to a chrome driver version or selenium grid version but this wouldn't explain the other tests passing and this one test passing every so often.

The tests are running on a selenium grid that is hosted by docker containers.

It seems odd it is only affecting this one test, its configuration and execution is no different to the other tests just the steps it's performing but it doesn't even get as far as the tests.

If I restart the docker containers and essentially clean the grid, it seems to pass manually from my visual studio when I run it on its own.

But when I run the Jenkins job which runs them all it fails

Any thoughts?

Stack trace

```
Error Message
System.InvalidOperationException : unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
from unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from tab crashed
  (Session info: headless chrome=64.0.3282.140)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881),platform=Linux 4.9.77-31.58.amzn1.x86_64 x86_64)
TearDown : OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : no such session
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881),platform=Linux 4.9.77-31.58.amzn1.x86_64 x86_64)
Stacktrace
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
   at MoneyUITests.Methods.General.WaitForElementAndSelectDd(String dropdown, String option) in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Money - LeadGenTests\MoneyUITests\Methods\General.cs:line 242
   at MoneyUITests.Steps.Banking.LoanSteps.WhenIFillInTheSecredLoanComparisonForm() in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Money - LeadGenTests\MoneyUITests\Steps\Banking\LoanSteps.cs:line 36
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStepMatch(BindingMatch match, Object[] arguments)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(IContextManager contextManager, StepInstance stepInstance)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnAfterLastStep()
--TearDown
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.GetScreenshot()
   at MoneyUITests.Methods.General.TakeScreenshot(Object methodName) in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Money - LeadGenTests\MoneyUITests\Methods\General.cs:line 548
   at MoneyUITests.Methods.BaseContext.AfterScenario() in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Money - LeadGenTests\MoneyUITests\Methods\BaseContext.cs:line 46
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.InvokeHook(IBindingInvoker invoker, IHookBinding hookBinding, HookType hookType)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.FireEvents(HookType hookType)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnScenarioEnd()
```

**Update** :

This was not down to a memory issue, this was found to be a timing issue.

Which is probably why it was intermittent, I debugged by commenting out everything and trial and error on what line it failed on.

After much back and forth to why it was failing, I found putting a Thread.Sleep in front of it solved the error and the test carried out correctly.

But to why it was failing in this way and not an unknown element exception I have no idea.

Comment: Your code trials, error stack trace and relevant _HTML_ please.

Comment: A tab can crash if there's not enough memory.

Comment: I have commented out all tests bar 2, i have only 1 node on the selenium grid. 1 passes and the others throws this error. If i run it locally i have no issues. If i run it locally against a clean gird then it passes. but through jenkins it seems to be failing every time.....

Comment: Maybe your Jenkins box is low on memory?

Comment: @BrianMitchell Tough to tell `why it was failing` unless you share your code trial.

Answer (score -1):

i update  chromedriver=2.40.565383 to ChromeDriver=2.41.578700 ,platform=Linux 4.4

also add i run

sudo apt-get update

Comment: Please approve the suggested edit. As this answer is unreadable.